# How can I can add a new key/value to an existing dictionary in typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have this:

```
let mp = {
     transaction_amount: Number(data.amount_total),
     description: 'signature',
     payment_method_id: paymentType,
    }

if (paymentType !== 'credit_card') {
     mp.token = data.token
}
```

but typescript is saying token doesnt exist on type mp, how can I add the key 'token' there with its value?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the type of an object, TypeScript will generate one implicitly when you create it. So you should specify the type of the object, and make the token optional.

```js
type MP = {
    transaction_amount: number;
    description: string;
    payment_method_id: whatever_payment_type_is;
    token?: whatever_the_token_might_be;
};

let mp: MP = { 
     // etc
```

Comment: I tried this way but when I was declaring the type and used '?' it said: 'An object member cannot be declared optional.'

Comment: @Fernanda — I can't reproduce that problem: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvGCC2ICuYUA+lCMgDYBcMAjAEwDMANDGQNYCmYNARAhESDeMAL4BuAFChIsAA4IAnjm5QAKormca0AE4BLMAHM0MXgDMQIXlMlRNnGAFkACqYySYXtroSQEwFD64MS4BEQ0YPg4AEaculLe8JwQwAZyQeA6UAbGid4KyqrEKlAAFiBwxPpw2blG+V4c3AD8dYYNkhKSkhScsDhyNK7unkk5fhABmWCheIRQNABy0XG6ABSIyAB0YQuk5AgUAJTMY95wKWn6GcE8MADkEPpGYEj4upwPZ0kwhSpEEr9CpVGo0f6qDRaH7eUQ9fTmGDrCFEKGOACEqHQDzSnDg+hIwAQujgD2OmHOXkG22aYFMWwQNJAXDAXSAA

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the same underlying runtime, but you can do

```
let mp = {
  transaction_amount: Number(data.amount_total),
  description: 'signature',
  payment_method_id: paymentType,
  token: paymentType !== 'credit_card' ? data.token : undefined
}
```

and still get the right types as long as you don't have strict requirements on the existence of the `token` key.

Comment: I can't have the key if its other payment type so undefined will not do

Comment: There are other options, but they require runtime changes. Quentin's answer is the simplest you can use without changes.